# Unity Editor - validating GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Task:**

I want to create a context menu item that will work on `GameObject` selected in `Hierarchy`. This action should be available only when selected `GameObject` is a `Prefab`. I'm working on **Unity 5.3.2**

[image]

**Code:**

File MenuItems.cs is located in **Assets\Editor**

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public static class MenuItems
{

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Action on prefab", false, 14)]
    private static void MenuActionPrefab()
    {
    }

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Action on prefab", true, 14)]
    private static bool ValidateMenuActionPrefab()
    {
        var isPrefab = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(Selection.activeGameObject) != null;
        return isPrefab;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that the menu item is visible (and can be clicked) no matter if selected `GameObject` is a `Prefab` or not. I have tested code in debugger and value returned from `ValidateMenuActionPrefab()` is OK (`true` when I run it on Prefab, `false` on non-prefab gameobject).

I've read somewhere that Unity 5 have problem with validation methods but the example from [UNITY EDITOR EXTENSIONS – MENU ITEMS](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/unity-editor-extensions-menu-items) about validation in `Assets` work perfectly OK.

**Question:**

So if this is a proper solution? Or is there another way to achieve same goal?

**Additional info:**

I have tried to run those methods simple way using:

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Action on prefab")]
```

and

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/Action on prefab", true)]
```

but in this case there is no `Action on prefab` in context menu. Also this item isn't visible when I try not to set priority index.

**Edit:**

Behaviour should be simillar to `Select Prefab` item (visible on screenshot). When object isn't connected to prefab field should be grey and not-clickable. When object is a prefab field is black and can be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I've just set up a new unity3d project and your code works then clicking on the menu Gameobject/Action on Asset.

I'm using Unity3d 5.3.4f1. Maybe it's a bug in your specific version, however I didn't find any mention about this neither in the 5.3.3 nor the 5.3.4 changelog

However when you right-click and open the context menu over an object in the hierarchy, the ValidationMethod **is not** called, so the context menu element is always enabled. *But* if you actually click the context menu item, then the validation method **is** called; if it returns `false` then no action is performed.

Seems like a bug, but at least is safe to use it.

**Prefab selected**

[image]

**Instance selected**

[image]

Comment: Not yet, but as i said, code `isPrefab = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(Selection.activeGameObject) != null;` return proper value. Problem is that in `Editor` field `Action on prefab` is visible also on `prefab` and `non-prefab` objects.

Comment: so in your editor when you select non-prefab object this field is gray and can't be clicked?

Comment: Yep, I've attached a couple of shots

Comment: It's a good news than. What about context menu, right mouse button on gameobject in hierarchy, same results?

Comment: Nope,  context menu does not work. Just debugged and the ValidateMenuActionPrefab is not being called in the context menu (it does using the app menu)

Comment: I've just run some tests: using a context menu, the element in the menu is ALWAYS available. However if you click on it, the validation method is called! If it returns false it doesn't perform the action. So it seems they are calling the validation method at the wrong time with context menus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114466/discussion-between-ricardo-amores-and-pawel-marecki).